# Redirect pages using. htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

How to use .htaccess redirect page when the url ".php" or ".html" or "?" or "=" ?

```
Examples
http://www.domain.ltd/index.php     # error, execute redirect to http://www.domain.ltd/ban/
http://www.domain.ltd/index/?id=foo # error, execute redirect to http://www.domain.ltd/ban/
http://www.domain.ltd/index.html    # error, execute redirect to http://www.domain.ltd/ban/
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Snippet taken from: http://www.webconfs.com/how-to-redirect-a-webpage.php

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
rewritecond %{http_host} ^domain.com [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

obviously replace domain.com with your page. This redirect will look at anything coming to domain.com and forward it to www.domain.com.

A quick Google produced this nice htaccess generator for me too (but I can't post it at the moment).

Comment: But it does not answer my question :-(

Comment: Try the following, you might need to play with where it's redirected to: RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /ban [NC,R]